# Multiply two column datagridview cell values for another column then sum values of all rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum

I have this datagridview where I sum all time under tension value with this code:

```
    int finalSum = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++p)
  {
     finalSum += getCellDigitSum(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[p].Cells[4].Value));
  }
    
 label22.Text = finalSum.ToString();
    
 int getCellDigitSum(int cellValue)
   {
     int l = cellValue;
     int result = 0;
    
     while (l > 0)
       {
         result += (l % 10);
    
         l = l / 10;
       }
    
    return result;
 }
```

With this code I obtain the sum of single values (201 become 3) and then the sum of all rows.

The problem is that I need to first multiply the "Serie" column value for the "Ripetizioni" value, then multiply the result for the sum of multiple digits "time under tension" (201 will be 3) and at the end multiply the result for all the rows.

This is the datagridview [image: datagridview]

So for example in the first row I need to do 11 x 3 = result x (201 sum so 3).

Loop for all the rows and do the sum of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. let me know incase you face any issue. Calculation can be modified according to requirement.

```
        int finalSum = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++p)
        {
            finalSum += getCellDigitSum(dataGridView1.Rows[p]);
        }

        //label22.Text = finalSum.ToString();

        int getCellDigitSum(DataGridViewRow dr)
        {
            int serie = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[0].Value);//you can change cell index or use column name
            int ripetizioni = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[1].Value);//you can change cell index or use column name
            //timeundertension
            int l = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[3].Value);
            int sumTimeUnderTension = 0;

            int result = 0;

            while (l > 0)
            {
                sumTimeUnderTension += (l % 10);

                l = l / 10;
            }

            result = serie * ripetizioni * sumTimeUnderTension;
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: yes, I only deleted the "//" before label22.Text and works! Thank you!